# Train a Neural Network in google cloud with my train and eval files in my PC

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions, conv-neural-network

I want to train a CNN in google cloud, but I have a problem, I do not want to upload my training and evaluation files to the cloud because they weigh too much and uploading them is a lot of time, when executing the command with the addresses of my files on my PC I have an error, which says that it does not find the routes, but these are already reviewed and they are correct, this is the command:

`gcloud ml-engine jobs submit training $JOB_NAME \--job-dir $OUTPUT_PATH \--runtime-version 1.8 \--module-name Programa.Quinta_Version \--package-path /Users/David/Desktop/David/Tesis/Practica/Programas/Versiones/Quinta_Version/Programa \--region $REGION \-- \--train-files /Users/David/Desktop/David/Tesis/Practica/Programas/Versiones/Quinta_Version/Record/Train_TFRecord \--eval-files /Users/David/Desktop/David/Tesis/Practica/Programas/Versiones/Quinta_Version/Record/Eval_TFRecord`

I get this error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8dqW.png)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DLE4.png)

I ran it locally and it runs without problems, I have that error only when I want to run in the cloud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Training and evaluation data must be stored in a location that your Google Cloud Platform project can access, typically a Google Cloud Storage location or in Google BigQuery. Google Cloud cannot directly access your home desktop's hard disk.

You'll either need to upload your data to the cloud, or you'll need to train locally on your own hardware and then upload the finished model to the cloud.